# how to make search bar input field in centre?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm making a demo in which a header is there and a search bar is there (see image). I am able to make the header. I need a search bar which is horizontally centered with a search icon. Can we make in ionic this type of input field?

Here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPKxra

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
      <title>Tabs Example</title>
      <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
 <ion-view ng-controller="showhidecntr">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear backbtnClass">back</a>
            <!--i style="font-size:30px;" class='icon ion-chevron-left'></i-->
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>





    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at [`inset input`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-input-inset) or [`header input`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#bar-inputs) shown in the docs.

Comment: wait checking ...will tell you

Comment: first please check my full image ..search bar is not with header it is individual

Comment: could you please use code pen